# How does Dayananda Saraswati explain the Purusha Sukta of the Rigveda?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, purusha, dayananda-saraswati

Maharshi Dayananda Saraswati was believer in pure Vedic Hinduism (as per his notion). Now he wrote Rigveda bhashya on Rigveda.

[Purusha Sukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purusha_Sukta) is hymn 10.90 of Rigveda. Read it on [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_10/Hymn_90).

Now, I want to know how Dayanand ji himself explained Purusha sukta. It is of very critical importance.

Archive.org contains his bhashya but in all the mandalas listed there, I am not able to find it even after searching.

Can somebody explain here or give exact direct link to Dayanand Saraswati's explanation of Purusha sukta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, he has explained Purushasukta as well. You can get word-to-word Sanskrit-Hindi translation of Dayanad Sarasvati's Rigveda Bhashya from [AryaSamaj, Jamnagar](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/) as I've mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21707/277). 5th volume contains 9th and 10th Mandala of Rigveda you may read [online](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v5/rugveda.htm). [English version](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in) seems incomplete.

Since you're interested in PurushSukta 90<sup>th</sup> Sukta of 10<sup>th</sup> Mandala, you can directly jump to [894<sup>th</sup> page](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v5/pages/p894.gif) from where PurushSukta starts and ends at [pg. 901](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v5/pages/p901.gif). To get the pages you just need to download gif from url `http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v5/pages/p894.gif` (change page no. accordingly from 894 to 901 before `.gif` in the url)

Quoting the Vishesha Vaktavya (special saying) for Purush Sukta:

> [image]

Translating into English:

This Sukta is known as Purusha Sukta. Purusha=Paramatma, Jivatma and Prakriti are described in this Sukta. The evaluation is not only physical. Prakriti is Purushatmaka. The formation of nice society is not possible without knowing Samsara and it's creation process. That's why Samsara as well as Samaja (society) is described in this Sukta. The description of society is also done by describing Paramatma, Jivatma, forces of Prakriti and the process of creation. The equality/similarity of Sharira (physical body) and Brahmanda
(universe) is also shown.

Read the commentary and translation (page 894-901) to know the explanation by Dayanad Saraswati.

Comment: "**Read the commentary and translation** (page 894-901) **to know the explanation by Dayanad Saraswati**" - Can you add the gist of the commentary in your answer? Simply pointing to links of Hindi commentary is not very helpful and doesn't address the title question "How does Dayananda Saraswati explain the Purusha Sukta of the Rigveda?"